# Being considered volunteer for answering questions?

Tags: discussion

My company gives us $10 per hour for working for any nonprofit organization and I can use that money to donate to whichever charity I want from Benevity. The requirement is someone from the nonprofit needs to tell them (when asked) how much time I spent working for the nonprofit organization. I know SO is not a nonprofit. Is there any possibility/program for us to reply to questions here and get that reported as volunteer work? Are there any organizations that SO partners with? I think my best use of time would be to use my skills first to help people rather than another type of help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a for profit company!

Comment: Very, VERY, for profit. One of the regulars around here has a dig about just how profitable in their name.

Comment: Please feel free to help anyway, though.

Comment: @greg-449 
   I know Stack Overflow is for profit -- but authors are not paid and help other people. Anyways that is a different discussion. do you have any other nonprofit places where software engineers can help?

Comment: Maybe https://www.fsf.org/

Comment: I don’t have a link right now, but someone asked something similar (SE verifying someone spent X amount of time helping for the purpose of volunteer hours) over on MSE. This was a bunch of months ago, and it may have been severed (not sure), but it may be helpful if you can find it

Comment: Related/similar request over on MSE [Community service hours on SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378054/1099857) (perhaps this is the one @cocomac was referring to)

Comment: @HenryEcker Yep, that is what I was thinking of

Comment: It is conceivable that you could volunteer for a registered non-profit software developer answering Stack Overflow questions related to their software.  However, you'd need to coordinate that with the non-profit rather than Stack Overflow itself (as Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange is a for-profit company).  I'm not aware of any non-profit currently doing this.

Comment: I don't understand why the question is poorly received. Notwithstanding that the for-profit nature of the site won't meet OP's apparent requirements, it seems perfectly reasonable to ask whether and how it is possible to get certification of having spent time improving Stack Overflow; and doing so clearly is volunteer work.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the fact SO is *not* non-profit company is well known and absolutely public. mcvkr could have easily clarified that they know that in the question. Without that question seem to be based on an obviously false premise - whether such questions deserve downvotes is everyone's personal call, but I can see why some would downvote (apparently, I did not.... which is surprising for me :) )

Comment: Okay updated the question. I am surprised that most people assumed I did not know SO is a for-profit organization when I asked the question. Some companies partner with nonprofits for things like helping job search, learning programming, or feeding people. I was curious if SO has anything similar to that in an event or something we could do it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To answer the direct question:  Stack Overflow is a for-profit company.  The work done around here is largely facilitated by volunteers, but the company itself does intend to pull a profit.  You need to clarify with your employer if that is enough of a distinction.